# Query amount of VRAM or GPU clock speed

Tags: vulkan

I am writing code to pick a physical device, but I want to put in some logic to prefer newer devices (more VRAM or higher clock speed) in case multiple ones fit my minimum feature requirements.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vulkan has no specific API calls to get such GPU details, for that you'd need to go with vendor specific APIs like NVAPI. The only hint may be `deviceType` member of `VkPhysicalDeviceProperties` that returns whether it's an integraed, discrete or virtual GPU.

The VRAM size though can be determined by finding the memory heap with the DEVICE_LOCAL bit set using `vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties`. The `VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties` returned by that function contains all available memory heaps in the `memoryHeaps` member. The configuration differs esp. between discrete and integrated GPUs, so this may not always be what you're looking for, e.g. on integrated GPUs with shared memory.

Heaps for a discrete GPU: http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=1432#memoryheaps

Heaps for an integrated GPU: http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=1200#memoryheaps